# Add Track Changes and comments in MS Word using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ms-word, office-interop

I can create and open Word document using C#. I am able to insert some new text, but now I am trying to insert track changes and comments on this document.

I've tried with some libraries but this was unsuccessful. Is anybody faced with this type of problem or know some libraries (free or commercial) who can help me in the finding solution of this problem.

Here is the code for creating and adding a text in a new Word document, on this document I want to add track changes, but I don't know how:

```
public static void CreateDocument()
{
    try
    {
        //Create an instance for word app
        Word.Application winword = new Word.Application();

        //Set animation status for word application
        winword.ShowAnimation = false;

        //Set status for word application is to be visible or not.
        winword.Visible = false;

        //Create a missing variable for missing value
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        //Create a new document
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        //adding text to document
        document.Content.SetRange(0, 0);
        document.Content.Text = "In this text I should add track changes " + Environment.NewLine;

        //Allow track changes, but I don't know how to use now
        document.TrackRevisions = true;

        //Save the document
        object filename = @"c:\temp1.docx";
        document.SaveAs2(ref filename);
        document.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        document = null;
        winword.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        winword = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

As a workaround you may consider using the Open XML SDK if you deal with open XML documents only, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Or you may consider using third-party components designed for the server-side execution.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating you own Version mechanism, don't you want to use the one that Word already have? I suppose [Revisions](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Show-or-hide-Track-Changes-revision-marks-a4d2241c-a014-4b83-be3b-8dfe8ea23ba7) is what you're looking for.

There is [Revision Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.revision.aspx) that have [all info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.revisions_members(v=office.14).aspx) that you may needed.

Comment: This Revision Interface is using just for accepting or rejecting all track changes in the document. I am looking for a tool which be able programmatically to insert track changes in some part of the text in word document.